# Angular JS How to invoke the directive scope functions from the directive template content events

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to access the events like onChange or onKeypress  of the input control, which I kept in the directive.I am able to access the variables which i declared in the "directive / controller / scope" (for example, scope variable , directiveVar ) but i am unable to invoke the myinput function directive (which is also declared in scope) for the onChange event of the input control.

I know this question is asked many times, but honestly i am trying to find what is the search keyword for this. Because, we have link and compile for the directives which bind the events. But coming to my scenario, i just to call the directive controller scope function from the template.

I think i have to compile my directives template first? is it right.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
angular.module('myapp').directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: 'First name: <input type="text" name="fname" onChange="myinput()"><br> Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br> {{directiveVar}}',
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.color = '#0080ff';
        $scope.directiveVar = "I am directive varible";
        $scope.myinput = function() {
            console.log('This is the myinput');
        }
    }
  };
});

angular.module('myapp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.color = '#ffb399';
    $scope.controllerVar = "I am controller varible";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
    <title>AngularJS: UI-Router Quick Start</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br /> 
  <hello-world/>

<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-bootstrap-contextmenu/contextMenu.js"></script>

<script src="lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: onChange(syntax is onchange) wont call the angulars method.If that is the pure javascript function it will call.use ng-change instead of that.There is no connection between onchange attribute and controllers method.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [ngChange directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) (note that it requires `ngModel`)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ngChange-directive-production</title>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
    angular.module('myapp').directive('helloWorld', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:
          'First name: <input type="text" ng-model="fname"><br>' +
          'Last name: <input type="text" ng-model="lname" ng-change="onChange()"><br>' +
          '{{fname + " " + lname}}',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.fname = 'fname';
            $scope.lname = 'lname';

            $scope.onChange = function(v) {
               alert('change');
            };
        }
      };
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <hello-world></hello-world>
</body>
</html>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X88nwXye15iCn3UL2GSV?p=preview)

> I think i have to compile my directives template first? is it right.

No, template is compiled once by angular, there is a special `compile` hook for that. More on the topic here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are trying to use the html built-in `onChange` event, which is outside of the Angularjs world. Your call to `myInput`, looks for a global regular function named `myInput`, which doesn't exist.
Use `ng-change=myInput()` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) instead.
This call will look for the `myInput` function in the scope.

By the way, notice that even if you had a global myInput function, changes made by the function might not take effect, since angular doesn't know you have changed elements in the scope and doesn't know it should render changes on the html etc.